# Получить имя таблиц в базу

Tags: sql, table, таблицы

У меня есть такое код.

```
$sql = "SELECT id,title FROM `data` WHERE ($title LIKE '%$word%') UNION SELECT id,title FROM `grigoryan` WHERE ($title LIKE '%$word%')";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
<a href="search?id=<?=$row['id'];?>"><?=$row['title']?></a>
```

в результате получил ссылка на страница поиск с ID и названия запроса. Например:

```
<a href="search?id=12">Как устроит?</a>
```

Но у меня нужно еще один элемент. Я хочу как это:

```
<a href="search?id=12&table=[имя таблица]">Как устроит?</a>
```

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Если вы обрабатываете запрос к таблице `data`, вы уже знаете ее название. Просто добавьте  `<a href="search?id=<?=$row['id'];?>&table=data">`

Comment: нет, у запрос ест несколько таблицы. В примере есть 2 таблица. Можно более.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно добавить еще одно поле в union с именем таблицы

```
$sql = "SELECT id,title, 'data' as tablename FROM `data` WHERE ($title LIKE '%$word%') 
        UNION 
        SELECT id,title, 'grigoryan' as tablename FROM `grigoryan` WHERE ($title LIKE '%$word%')";
```

затем вы можете использовать значение этого поля

```
<a href="search?id=<?=$row['id'];?>&table=<?=$row['tablename'];?>">
```

Comment: спасибо, заработал...